# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bokeh.plotting.helpers' with bkcharts

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I am trying to create a Scatter charts using **bokeh** in **Jupyter Notebook** version 6.0.3 but it's giving me **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bokeh.plotting.helpers'** I have installed bokeh and bkcharts using `pip install bokeh` and `pip install bkcharts`.

Here is my code

```
from bkcharts import Scatter, output_file, show
import pandas

df=pandas.DataFrame(columns=["X","Y"])
df["X"]=[1,2,3,4,5]
df["Y"]=[5,6,4,5,3]


p=Scatter(df, x="X",y="Y", title="temperature observations", xlabel="Day", ylabel="Temp")

output_file("Scatter_charts.html")
show(p)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `bkcharts` for any reason. It was deprecated and removed from the main Bokeh project several years ago. It is ***abandoned*** and ***unmaintained***. In order to use it today, you would also have to install an ancient Bokeh version 0.12.7 (or older).

These days, anything you might want to do with `bkcharts` you can do just as well with the modern core Bokeh package.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["X","Y"])
df["X"] = [1,2,3,4,5]
df["Y"] = [5,6,4,5,3]

p = figure(title="temp observations", x_axis_label="Day", y_axis_label="Temp")
p.scatter(x="X", y="Y", source=df)

output_file("scatter.html")
show(p)
```

If you want an even higher level API on top of Bokeh you could consider one of these more current third-party projects:

- [Holoviews](http://holoviews.org/)
- [PandasBokeh](https://github.com/PatrikHlobil/Pandas-Bokeh)
- [Chartify](https://github.com/spotify/chartify)